# C# Error using GetAsyncKeyState on ubuntu

Tags: c#, ubuntu

I'm trying to make a simple keylogger program in monodevelop (Ubuntu), but I keep getting the following error:
[image: The Error that i get]

Here's my code:

```
class MainClass
{
    [DllImport ("user32.dll")]
    static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(Int32 vKey);
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        MessageBox.Show ("Started");
        LogKeys ();
    }

    static void LogKeys()
    {
        MessageBox.Show ("Called");
        KeysConverter conv = new KeysConverter ();
        String text = "";
        while (true) 
        {
            Thread.Sleep (6);
            for (Int32 i = 0; i < 255; i++) 
            {
                Int32 key = GetAsyncKeyState (i);
                if (key == 1 || key == -32767)
                {
                    text += conv.ConvertToString (i);

                }

            }
        }
    }

}
```

Is it because I'm using monodevelop? Or is it because I'm not on an actual Windows machine?

Comment: @Adrian , thank you for taking time from your precious life to edit my post instead of actually helping me, this community is so awesome and helpful and definitely not toxic and awful. 

I am very thankful for asking my question and waking up to see someguy edited my tiny grammar mistakes and got approved and the fact that i cannot decline the edit, and i still have no answer.

Thank you! wonderful community

Comment: Hi, "@CoolGuy". You need to understand that spelling and grammar are actually considered important on this site (see: [Quality Standards Error](http://stackoverflow.com/help/quality-standards-error), and [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)). I edited your question as part of a review queue that is for making sure questions are written up to the quality that is expected on this site. You yourself can get access to once your [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) has reached a sufficient level.

Comment: Secondly, don't attack the help. Whilst it's easy to be cynical when you get no responses, it only hurts your cause and lessens the chance that you will actually get an answer. See [What should I do If no one answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers) for what you should be doing instead.

Comment: Now whilst I'm pretty good with C#, I have very little experience in using it outside of the Windows stack. So I can only generously speculate on the problem that your facing. But before I do, I ask you this: have you made an effort to research this problem yourself, or have you posted the problem immediately on this site without doing anything else? If you have researched, please edit your question and include the details. Have you also checked to see if you have the user32.dll library in your environment and that it has the method your trying to call?

Answer (score 0):

GetASyncKeyState() is a native Windows API function from the user32 library, it is not a .NET function.  MonoDevelop lets you build .NET mono applications that work on both linux and Windows but your Linux machine does not have access to native Windows API functions, this is the source of your problem.  You would need to find an equivalent method of detecting key presses in .NET.

The benefit of GetAsyncKeyState is that it's global and will detect key presses even if the process's window isn't the target focus.  You would need to find similar functionality in .NET to accomplish the same task.